# Count the spaces, commas, and points that appear in a string using switch statement in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdioh.>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char a[100];
int i,contor=0;
printf("Introduceti sirul: ");
gets(a);
switch(a)
{
case ',':
    contor++;
    break;
case '.':
    contor++;
    break;
case ' ':
    contor++;
    break;
default:
    printf("Nu exista spatii,virgule sau puncte.");
}
printf("Numarul de spatii, virgule si puncte este: %d",contor);
return 0;
}
```

I tried here but it gives me an error - switch quantity not an integer
     Someone help?:))I can't resolve this

Answer (score 0):

`switch(a)` won't work because `a` is an array (decayes to a pointer to char). You probably want something like:

```
    char *cp= a;
    while (*cp)
    {
        switch(*cp)
        {
            case ',':
                    contor++;
                    break;
            // etc
        }
        cp++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(expression) {
   case constant-expression  :
...
   default : //Optional
      statement(s);
}
```

> The *expression* used in a switch statement must have an integral or
>   enumerated type, or be of a class type in which the class has a single
>   conversion function to an integral or enumerated type.

In other words, you cannot use the entire input string as expression to the switch statement. A perfectly working example is given by Paul Ogilvie above.